# Como obter ID clicando num Elemento adicionado dinamicamente

Tags: php, javascript

Estou recebendo dentro de uma **div** novos elementos via PHP usando **XMLHttpRequest**.
Até ai tudo bem, obtenho os elementos e exibe tudo certinho, porém estou não estou conseguindo obter o ID desses novos elementos utilizando o evento de `Click`.

Ex:

```
<div id="res"> 
    <li class="new" id="50">Novo Elemento</li> 
    <!-- aqui é inserido o novo elemento via XMLHttpRequest (do PHP). -->
</div>
```

no meu JS faço (mas não funciona):

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('new');
for(var i = 0; i < el.length; i++){
    el[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
       alert( this.getAttribute('id') ); //aqui seria o ID que to precisando. :(
    }, false);
}
```

Preciso de algo semelhante ao code abaixo, só que em JavaScript(Puro) sem usar JQuery:

```
$('#res').on('click', 'li.new', function(){
    alert( $(this).attr('id') ); //aqui retorna certo...
});
```

Pesquisei pelo Google mas não encontrei nada.

Como poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer um delegador próprio.

Se só houver `li` dentro da div então o `e.target.id` deve dar o que precisa, senão tem de verificar `e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'li'` primeiro. Pode juntar ainda uma condição para verificar a classe. Usando classList.contains ou `className.indexOf('new') != -1`

Por exemplo:

```
var res = document.getElementById('res');
res.addEventListener('click', function(e){
       var elemento = e.target;
       if (elemento.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'li' && elemento.classList.contains('new')) alert(elemento.id);
       else return false;
}, false);
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/fz6368a9/

Comment: Se entendi bem, o próprio `#res` é insirido dinamicamente

Comment: @bfavaretto se o #res também fôr dinamico então o event handler pode ser adicionado à `window`: http://jsfiddle.net/9374tgbf/

Comment: @Sergio deu certo era isso mesmo que eu precisava. Obrigado